# Post Function Script: Set Value of Custom Field

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

I have a requirement to automatically populate a custom field during a particular workflow transition. This field is called "Owner" and should be populated with the name of the asignee.

I am new to scripting post functions, so as a first step, I tried the following code to attempt to populate that field with a test string. The workflow transition works, I see no errors, but the field remains empty.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.search.SearchService;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;

ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance();
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager();
CustomField cfOwner = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Owner"); IssueChangeHolder changeHolder = new DefaultIssueChangeHolder();
cfOwner.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(customFieldTarget), "Test"), changeHolder);
```

I would appreciate assistance to determine what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use in built post functions to achieve this.go to edit your workflow and select your transition need to be configure then click on post functions then navigate to add post function.

[image]

then select post function shown as the image then in next screen you can select your custom field and you can set the value as you need.
[image]